# xlearn predictions error give a different mse than output by the function

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, loss-function

the xlearn predict function gives a different mse than what you get by looking at the predictions and calculating it yourself. Here is code to do this; you can run it by cloning the [xlearn repository](https://github.com/aksnzhy/xlearn) and copying the below code in `demo/regression/house_price` in the repository

```
# Copyright (c) 2018 by contributors. All Rights Reserved.                                                                                                   
#                                                                                                                                                            
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");                                                                                            
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.                                                                                           
# You may obtain a copy of the License at                                                                                                                    
#                                                                                                                                                            
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0                                                                                                             
#                                                                                                                                                            
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software                                                                                        
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,                                                                                          
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.                                                                                   
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and                                                                                        
# limitations under the License.                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                             
import xlearn as xl                                                                                                                                          
import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                          
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                             
# Training task                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                             
# param:                                                                                                                                                     
#  0. regression task                                                                                                                                        
#  1. learning rate: 0.2                                                                                                                                     
#  2. regular lambda: 0.002                                                                                                                                  
#  3. evaluation metric: mae                                                                                                                                 
fm_model = xl.create_linear()  # Use factorization machine                                                                                                   
fm_model.setTrain("./house_price_train.txt")    # Training data                                                                                              
fm_model.setValidate("./house_price_test.txt")  # Validation data                                                                                            
fm_model.disableNorm()                                                                                                                                       
# fm_model.setSigmoid()                                                                                                                                      
# fm_model.disableEarlyStop()                                                                                                                                
param = {'task':'reg', 'lr':0.0002,                                                                                                                          
        'lambda':0.00001, 'metric':'rmse', 'epoch':100}                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                             
# Start to train                                                                                                                                             
# The trained model will be stored in model.out                                                                                                              
print("here")                                                                                                                                                
fm_model.fit(param, './model.out')                                                                                                                           
fm_model.setTest("./house_price_test.txt")  # Test data                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                             
# Prediction task                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                             
# Start to predict                                                                                                                                           
# The output result will be stored in output.txt                                                                                                             
outs = fm_model.predict("./model.out", "./output.txt")                                                                                                       
true = pd.read_csv("./house_price_test.txt", sep='\t', header=None)[0]                                                                                       
# print(true)                                                                                                                                                
preds = pd.read_csv("./output.txt", header=None)[0]                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                             
# Calculate using sklearn                                                                                                                                    
print(mean_squared_error(true, preds))                                                                                                                       
# Self calculate                                                                                                                                             
sq = 0.0                                                                                                                                                     
for t, p in zip(true, preds):                                                                                                                                
    sq += (t - p) ** 2                                                                                                                                       
print(sq/len(true))
```

If you save it as min_eg.py, run it (after installing xlearn) as
`python min_eg.py` simply.

Here is the output you get:

[image: output snapshot]

Interestingly the MSE you get is always exactly double of the reported mse from the predict function.

Any help is greatly appreciated; and I wonder if other folks have encountered the same issue.

Comment: You mean the comparison between "Test lost" and MSE. The sklearn code is python, but xlearn is in C, maybe the C implementation? Perhaps good to ask to the people who are working in that package.

Comment: I posted this on their github - https://github.com/aksnzhy/xlearn/issues/357

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of people use 1/2 MSE for the loss because it makes the derivative "easier". Given that they use the word "loss" rather than "MSE" or something like that, I'd bet this is what's going on.

For clarity, if your loss is

1/2n * [(y_1 - p_1)^2 + ... + (y_n - p_n)^2]

then the derivative (wrt p) would be

-1/n * [(y_1 - p_1) + ... + (y_n - p_n)]

The 2 goes away because you end up multiplying by 2 for the power rule.

pardon the formatting... I don't know how to do math stuff here.

Answer (score 1):

### It is exactly `MSE / 2`

Long story short: the MSE Loss of `xlearn` library is, as you mentioned, `MSE / 2`.

Doing some forensics on your use case, I can confirm that the `SquaredLoss`, as it is named in the core library, has a `*0.5` factor in its calculations.

Below you can follow my steps to verify by yourself this conclusion.

### How to verify it

#### Step 1.

Standing on `xlearn/src`, run
`grep -r "The test loss is" *`. It will point you to `solver/inference.cc`, line `62`:

[`https://github.com/aksnzhy/xlearn/blob/master/src/solver/inference.cc#L62`](https://github.com/aksnzhy/xlearn/blob/master/src/solver/inference.cc#L62)

Where you can see that the printed number is the `GetLoss` method of a `loss_` object.

Note that the python library is just a wrapper on top of this underlying library of C code.

#### Step 2.

This object is an instance of a loss. The two defined losses can be found under the folder `src/loss`. They are `cross-entropy` for classification and `squared loss` for regression:

[`https://github.com/aksnzhy/xlearn/tree/master/src/loss`](https://github.com/aksnzhy/xlearn/tree/master/src/loss)

#### Step 3.

Finally, you can check the header and the implementation of the `squared loss` here:

- [`https://github.com/aksnzhy/xlearn/blob/master/src/loss/squared_loss.h`](https://github.com/aksnzhy/xlearn/blob/master/src/loss/squared_loss.h)
- [`https://github.com/aksnzhy/xlearn/blob/master/src/loss/squared_loss.cc`](https://github.com/aksnzhy/xlearn/blob/master/src/loss/squared_loss.cc)

Where you can see that, although [in the `.h` file](https://github.com/aksnzhy/xlearn/blob/master/src/loss/squared_loss.h#L32) it says that the loss is:

`loss = sum_all_example( (y - pred) ^ 2 )`

The actual implementation in the file `.cc` has a `*0.5` factor in the calculations, both in lines [`37`](https://github.com/aksnzhy/xlearn/blob/master/src/loss/squared_loss.cc#L37) and [`100`](https://github.com/aksnzhy/xlearn/blob/master/src/loss/squared_loss.cc#L100).

### Theoretical reason

This is a normal practice in Machine Learning, based on the fact that the gradient descent method uses the derivative of the loss function. Having this `1/2` factor makes the derivative somehow tidier because, when deriving, the power of 2 turns into a `*2` factor that cancels out with this added `1/2`. The addition of this `1/2` factor, on the other hand, doesn't affect the metric from a training purpose, since the shape and the minimum are preserved.